# Adding together multiple dictionary key values that have the same key string

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Let's say my dictionary looks like this:

```
{
    "432701228292636694" : {
        "64AEdcb" : {
            "inviter" : "282764296075870208",
            "uses" : 40
        },
        "9WVmh3Q" : {
            "inviter" : "173219378492473345",
            "uses" : 26
        },
        "AE8ugEN" : {
            "inviter" : "285548207189000204",
            "uses" : 4
        },
        "EmCddbN" : {
            "inviter" : "193926566881918978",
            "uses" : 2
        },
        "GKnPWyW" : {
            "inviter" : "147756076299845632",
            "uses" : 1
        },
        "JnmyFKE" : {
            "inviter" : "173219378492473345",
            "uses" : 10
        },
        "Km4wZTz" : {
            "inviter" : "161132853256650752",
            "uses" : 9
        },
        "M8uYMNb" : {
            "inviter" : "193896125969858561",
            "uses" : 8
        },
        "e9vTXcz" : {
            "inviter" : "273852837988007936",
            "uses" : 1
        },
        "gTB7w4R" : {
            "inviter" : "327660257423917066",
            "uses" : 1
        },
        "hG2KyZa" : {
            "inviter" : "315630485114191872",
            "uses" : 2
        },
        "pdZNPFa" : {
            "inviter" : "141431182792458241",
            "uses" : 537
        },
        "rZwH4QF" : {
            "inviter" : "384664458628169728",
            "uses" : 4
        },
        "s9FXVAU" : {
            "inviter" : "125092433657593856",
            "uses" : 2
        },
        "wrPbkGz" : {
            "inviter" : "277605262486011904",
            "uses" : 3
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add up the totals for every key that has the same `inviter` to get a combined total of `uses`. In the data above, `inviter` "173219378492473345" keys with uses of 26 and 10. I want to be able to combine that as 36.

How can I achieve this? I am able to write a list comprehension statement that can get me the value of each, but adding them together and getting a total is where I get lost.

The code below is what I've already written:

```
codes = sorted(self.invites_db[server.id], key=lambda x: (self.invites_db[server.id][x]['uses']), reverse=True)
inviters = [server.get_member(self.invites_db[server.id][x]['inviter']).name + "#" + server.get_member(self.invites_db[server.id][x]['inviter']).discriminator for x in codes if self.invites_db[server.id][x]['inviter'] != "141431182792458241"]
uses = [self.invites_db[server.id][x]['uses'] for x in codes if self.invites_db[server.id][x]['inviter'] != "141431182792458241"]
```

This will give me a list of all `inviters` and `uses`, but I don't want to have two identical `inviter`s. Instead I want them to be added together as one. How can I do that so that I can them use `zip` to show this data side-by-side in text format?

Comment: In general it's good to make questions here as general as possible. So that other people might find the question useful. If you post a more general version then you are more likely to get an answer and an explanation

Answer (score 2):

`collections.Counter` for those kind of "count me or zero" stuff / accumulation problems (that you cannot solve with list comprehensions):

```
result = collections.Counter()
for subdict in d["432701228292636694"].values():
    result[subdict["inviter"]] += subdict["uses"]
```

result:

```
>>> result
{'125092433657593856': 2,
 '141431182792458241': 537,
 '147756076299845632': 1,
 '161132853256650752': 9,
 '173219378492473345': 36,
 '193896125969858561': 8,
 '193926566881918978': 2,
 '273852837988007936': 1,
 '277605262486011904': 3,
 '282764296075870208': 40,
 '285548207189000204': 4,
 '315630485114191872': 2,
 '327660257423917066': 1,
 '384664458628169728': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be a good time to use a simple dictionary?

```
uses = {}
for _,v in test["432701228292636694"].items():
    if v["inviter"] in uses:
        uses[v["inviter"]] += v["uses"]
    else:
        uses[v["inviter"]] = v["uses"]

print (uses)
```

---

```
{'282764296075870208': 40, '173219378492473345': 36, '285548207189000204': 4, '193926566881918978': 2, '147756076299845632': 1, '161132853256650752': 9, '193896125969858561': 8, '273852837988007936': 1, '327660257423917066': 1, '315630485114191872': 2, '141431182792458241': 537, '384664458628169728': 4, '125092433657593856': 2, '277605262486011904': 3}
```

Comment: probably better with a `defaultdict`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dict is stored as variable `d`:

```
o = {}
for s in d.values():
    for i in s.values():
        o[i['inviter']] = o.get(i['inviter'], 0) + i['uses']
```

`o` would become:

```
{'125092433657593856': 2,
 '141431182792458241': 537,
 '147756076299845632': 1,
 '161132853256650752': 9,
 '173219378492473345': 36,
 '193896125969858561': 8,
 '193926566881918978': 2,
 '273852837988007936': 1,
 '277605262486011904': 3,
 '282764296075870208': 40,
 '285548207189000204': 4,
 '315630485114191872': 2,
 '327660257423917066': 1,
 '384664458628169728': 4}
```